# Header stamp: When is/should this be from?

Tags: ros-melodic, sensor-msgs, std-msgs, nav-msgs, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many messages in ROS include the header, which includes the timestamp.

What is best/expected practice for this?
Should the stamp be the time at which the message is sent or the time of the event it is describing.

In particular most nav_msgs and sensor_msgs have headers.  It would be my assumption that nav_msgs/odom would be stamped with the instant at which data were taken from the wheel encoders.  Likewise, sensor_msgs/LaserScan would be stamped with some time consistently offset with the start of the rev of the scanner.  This would then allow odometry and sensor data to be accurately fused.

Is this the case?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338327/header-stamp:-when-is/should-this-be-from?/) by [Dave Barnett](https://answers.ros.org/users/29647/dave-barnett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-11-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Should the stamp be the time at which the message is sent

No, typically not.

("typically, as in some cases you actually *do* want to know *when* something was published, such as when you're writing a benchmark of the ROS middleware (essentially doing `stamp(received)-stamp(sent)`).

> or the time of the event it is describing.

That would make the most sense when dealing with sensor data, yes.

I would make it slightly more generic: you'd set the field to the time at which something was *generated* or *captured* (not all publications have sensors as there sources).

And in case of algorithms that process sensor data, it's typically the case you'd *copy* the `stamp` field of the incoming message to the outgoing one, as that would allow you to correlate processed (or derived) data to other messages that were published at the time of the original data (example: correlating processed laser scans to odometry data).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NiranjanRavi](https://answers.ros.org/users/81000/niranjanravi/) on 2021-09-02**:
@gvdhoorn

Hi, thank you for the explanation. I have a clarification;

Node 1: I have a camera which captures images and send it to ROS queue.

Node 2: Subscribes to the topic and gets the images. I have also added a code called **timer = data.header.stamp** to extract the timestamp associated with the image.

My understanding is, the timer variable above corresponds to the timestamp at which image was captured by the camera (Node 1)
Or
does it indicate the timestamp at which image was subscribed from ROS queue using Node 2?

It would be helpful to know if this is correct.

Thanks